# Unexpected behavior after "Back" button

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, back

I have this text in my login screen:

[image]

the underlined text is clickable. I click Terms & Conditions:

[image]

And I am sent to this screen. Now, after clicking "Back":

1) Text is gone:

[image]

2) A nav-bar placeholder appears:

[image]

It looks like the appearance of this placeholder somehow shrinks the view.

"Before" pic of screen:

[image]

"After" pic of screen:

[image]

Also - what is the best method of making sure the two sign in buttons are the same size (height, width) and close to each other? I tried this:

```
FacebookSignInButton.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y: self.view.frame.height/2, width: GoogleSignInButton.frame.width, height: GoogleSignInButton.frame.height)
```

which didn't work (The view you can see now is using this line of code)

The code for viewing the T&C:

```
class PolicyViewController: UIViewController
{
    var policy = PolicyModel(policy: "")
    {
        didSet { updateViews() }
    }
    @IBOutlet var HeaderLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var TextToDisplay: UITextView!


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
        updateViews()
        Constants.logger.debug("PolicyViewController loaded")
    }

    private func updateViews()
    {
        guard isViewLoaded else { return }
        HeaderLabel.text = policy.title
        TextToDisplay.text = policy.body
    }
}
```

Code in my main login screen (where the text is clickable):

```
@IBAction func AcceptanceTextTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        let text = (AcceptanceText.text)!
        let termsRange = (text as NSString).range(of: LocalizationStrings.Login.TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS)
        let privacyRange = (text as NSString).range(of: LocalizationStrings.Login.PRIVACY_POLICY)

        if sender.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: AcceptanceText, inRange: termsRange)
        {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue_to_tc", sender: self)
        }
        else if sender.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: AcceptanceText, inRange: privacyRange)
        {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue_to_p", sender: self)
        }
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        switch (segue.identifier ?? "", segue.destination)
        {
            case ("segue_to_tc", let destination as PolicyViewController):
                destination.policy = PolicyModel(policy: "TS")
            case ("segue_to_p", let destination as PolicyViewController):
                destination.policy = PolicyModel(policy: "PP")
            case ("segue_facebook_login", let destination as UITabBarController) :
                prepareTabBarUI(tabBar: destination)

            default: super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        }
    }

// This extension serves to be able to identify tapping on the text of Acceptance and Privacy Policy
extension UITapGestureRecognizer
{
    func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool
    {
        // Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer()
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: label.attributedText!)

        // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        // Configure textContainer
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines
        let labelSize = label.bounds.size
        textContainer.size = labelSize

        // Find the tapped character location and compare it to the specified range
        let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.location(in: label)
        let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)

        let textContainerOffset = CGPoint( x: (labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x,
                                           y:  (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y);
        let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(x: locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x,
                                                     y: locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y);
        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

        return NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange)
    }

}
```

EDIT:

Storyboard image:

[image]

Comment: Please attach your code to understand briefly.

Comment: Added some code :)

Answer (score 0):

So you used segue to call another viewController using storyboard. But it seems that you used **Present Modally** segue to call another viewController. What you need to call is **Show (Push)**. You can read more about segue here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html
To Solve your problem just change your segue kind to Show like this in your storyboard

[image: Change]

Comment: What changes would you make to the code to perfect it?

Comment: It is acting the same exactly

Comment: Can you provide image of storyboard or sample project on github.

Comment: Added in EDIT :)

Comment: How do you come back from Next View Controller? Do you segue From B View Controller to A View Controller?

Comment: I just click the "Back" button in nav controller

Comment: Then i can't see any reason why it's not working for you. Why you don't you upload demo project in github. So anyone can look and solve it